# Wrong date is displayed in Magento Admin Dashboard

Tags: timezone, magento-1.9

I have an issue with the date and time being shown incorrect in magento admin dashboard. I have set the Timezone as Pacific Standard Time(America/Los_Angeles) through Configuration>system>General>Locale Options 
but the current Date in the admin dashboard is Sunday, February 7, 2016 where as it should be Tuesday, February 6, 2016. This is affecting the cron schedule which in turn is affecting the email queue. Could you please help me fix this. I am unable to find the module that is overriding the magento's default timezone.

Comment: Here is the Screenshot -[Dashboard](http://i.imgur.com/Hyfy5FH.png?1)